# Creating an image with text and saving it as .png in C# using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

We are working on an Optical Character Recognition system and i want to compare how different renderers render text. I want to make a simple program that creates an image, writes some text on it with different fonts, sizes and styles and saves it to a .png file(I want to have all sizes, fonts styles i need in one file so they are easy to compare). I've managed to do it with GDI and GDI+ renderers using Bitmap.
Now i'm trying to do the same thing in a WPF application, as I've heard rendering text there is different. Is it possible to use BitmapImage for that? Coming from Windows Forms I presume this problem should be pretty simple but i just can't seem to do it in WPF.

This is a simplified version of how i did it with GDI+ Renderer:

```
public void CreateAndSave()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    g.DrawString("sample text", font, brush, x, y);
    bitmap.Save(fileName);
}
```

Is there any similar way of doing this with WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Such as methods like "DrawString" are costly in WPF. Instead of that doing that, you can create a canvas/grid and put the text box or labels etc. and then you can render that canvas/grid. You can use that code:

```
public void ConvertToBitmapSource(UIElement element)
{
    var target = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)element.RenderSize.Width, (int)element.RenderSize.Height,
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    target.Render(element);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    var outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(target);
    encoder.Frames.Add(outputFrame);

    using (var file = File.OpenWrite("TestImage.png"))
    {
        encoder.Save(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This idea might work. The problem i have now is that i want a .png with a lot of different fonts and sizes and i would have to create a lot of labels to do that. Also when i use this method the text rendered in the .png is not the same as on the actual running application. That might be caused by the background being transparent. Is there a quick way of setting the background color of RenderTargetBitmap to white, or do i have to set every bit to white?

Comment: One way to that if you use a grid/canvas as UIElement, try to set the background of it as White. It will work

Comment: I changed the background to white, but it appears that the background wasn't causing bad quality of text. Maybe if it renders the whole element onto a RenderTargetBitmap it doesn't care about how the text was rendered earlier. I also tried to use this method on a single label but it still isn't doing it.

Comment: So text quality depends on also resolution and dpi. You can arrange them but file size will be greater

Comment: I set the dpi to 120 to match my systems dpi and its acceptably similar to the original. Thank you for help.

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to set where the element will be rendered on RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use such a code:  var crop = new CroppedBitmap(target , new Int32Rect(50, 50, 250, 250));

BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(crop));

Comment: This only lets me choose which part of bitmap i'm saving. What I want to do is to have one big bitmap and save multiple UI elements next to each other on it. I want to make a bitmap with rendered labels, then change those labels and render them on that bitmap next to the previous ones so i can see the differences.

Comment: Check that for example answer code. You can add many frames encoder.Frames.Add(outputFrame);

Answer (score 0):

Use the FormattedText class to build a Geometry object, take an example from here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx

Then, use one of the BitmapEncoder classes to save the Geometry object you've built. Look at that example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081295/3730455