# C# WPF DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn PackIcon Content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, material-design

I use [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) and [Material Design XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)

My View:

I have a Datagrid:

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

My ViewModel:

```cs
    public partial class ViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        DataTable _data;


        public ViewModel()
        {
            var currentData = new DataTable();
            currentData.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            currentData.Columns.Add("BooleanValue", typeof(bool));
            currentData.Columns.Add("Icon", typeof(PackIcon));


            //Two rows
            DataRow firstRow = currentData.NewRow();
            DataRow secondRow = currentData.NewRow();

            firstRow[0] = "Text1";
            firstRow[1] = true;
            firstRow[2] = new PackIcon { Kind = PackIconKind.SmileyHappy };
            secondRow[0] = "Text2"; 
            secondRow[1] = false;
            secondRow[2] = new PackIcon { Kind = PackIconKind.SmileyAngry };

            currentData.Rows.Add(firstRow);
            currentData.Rows.Add(secondRow);

            Data = currentData;
        }
    }
```

So far, so good.

The DataGrid shows `MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIcon` instead of the actual Icon.
I found the solution for [non-dynamic DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74251853/19658060) but this will not work for dynamic DataGrid.

The goal is that a specific cell will display the actual icon.

Because of the dynamic DataGrid I need `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`. The idea is that I intercept the AutoGenerateColumns, and everytime the type is `PackIcon`, I change the content.

For that reason, I intercept it:

```cs
 private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyType == typeof(PackIcon))
            {
                //todo 
            }
        }
```

I tried several things, but non seems to work. How is it possible to set the "content" to the actual PackIcon content. I thought, I could do something with `e.Column.CellStyle` but I found no way to convert a `IconPack` to a `Style`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358111/datagrid-shows-path-of-image-instead-of-image-itself

Comment: thanks @ASh but I couldn't create workable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to set the "content" to the actual PackIcon content.

You could create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ContentControl` that displays the icon:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(PackIcon))
    {
        const string Xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" +
            "<ContentControl Content=\"{{Binding {0}}}\"  />" +
            "</DataTemplate>";
        e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
        {
            Header = e.PropertyName,
            CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(string.Format(Xaml, e.PropertyName))
        };
    }
}
```